# TableView ---> DetailView

Tags: ios, xcode4

I would like the organization names on `TableView`, and find more information on `DetailView`. But I do not know where is error, `DetailView` is not find my information. Here is the `didSelectRow` code:

`TableView`:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    switch (section) {
        case 0:
            return 2;
            break;
        case 1:
            return 2;
            break;
        case 2:
            return 2;
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSString *sectionHeader = nil;    if(section == 0) {
        sectionHeader = @"Red Wine";
    }
    if(section == 1) {
        sectionHeader = @"White Wine";
    }
    if(section == 2) {
        sectionHeader = @"Sparkling Wine";
    }
    return sectionHeader;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
        [cell.textLabel setNumberOfLines:3];
    }
    switch (indexPath.section) {
        case 0: 
            switch (indexPath.row) {
                case 0:
                    cell.textLabel.text = @"Black Wattle Mt Benson Merlot 2008";
                    cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Mt Benson, South Australia.";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    cell.textLabel.text = @"Two Hands Canny Butcher Barossa Valley Shiraz Grenache Mataro 2009";
                    cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Barossa Valley, South Australia.";
                    break;
            }
            break;
        case 1: 
            switch (indexPath.row) {
                case 0:
                    cell.textLabel.text = @"Amberton Lizard Sauvignon Blanc Semillon 2011";
                    cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"South Eastern Australia.";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    cell.textLabel.text = @"Vasse Felix Margaret River Chardonnay Margaret River";
                    cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Western Australia.";
                break;          }
            break;
        case 2: 
            switch (indexPath.row) {
                case 0:
                    cell.textLabel.text = @"Janisson Fils Brut Non Vintage Champagne";
                    cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Champagne, France.";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    cell.textLabel.text = @"Francois Montand Brut Blanc De Blancs NV";
                    cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Premium French sparkling vineyard areas.";
                    break;
            }
            break;
    }
    return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    DetailViewController *ViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];

    ViewController.Wine = [indexPath section];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:ViewController animated:YES];
}
```

`DetailView`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{    
[super viewDidLoad];
switch (Wine) {
    case 0: 
        switch (Wine) {
            case 0:
                self.navigationItem.title = @"Black Wattle Mt Benson Merlot 2008";
                WineTextView.text = @"Alcohol: 14.5%\n"
                "\n"
                "Foods: Pan grilled fillet mignon with buttered mushrooms and silky mashed potatoes.\n";
                break;
            case 1:
                self.navigationItem.title = @"Two Hands Canny Butcher Barossa Valley Shiraz Grenache Mataro 2009";
                WineTextView.text =  @"Alcohol: 14.2%\n"
                "\n"
                "Foods: Enjoy with beef stew and winter vegetables.\n";
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
        break;

    case 1: 
        switch (Wine) {
            case 0:
                self.navigationItem.title = @"Amberton Lizard Sauvignon Blanc Semillon 2011";
                WineTextView.text = @"Alcohol: 14.5%\n"
                "\n"
                "Foods: Pan grilled fillet mignon with buttered mushrooms and silky mashed potatoes.\n";
                break;
            case 1:
                self.navigationItem.title = @"Vasse Felix Margaret River Chardonnay Margaret River";
                WineTextView.text = @"Alcohol: 12%\n"
                "\n"
                "Foods: Enjoy with Chinese roast duck salad.\n";
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        break;

    case 2: 
        switch (Wine) {
            case 0:
                self.navigationItem.title = @"Janisson Fils Brut Non Vintage Champagne";
                WineTextView.text = @"Alcohol: 12%\n"
                "\n"
                "Foods: Ideal aperitif style, to accompany canapés and hors doeuvres.\n";
                break;
            case 1:
                self.navigationItem.title = @"Francois Montand Brut Blanc De Blancs NV";
                WineTextView.text = @"Alcohol: 12%\n"
                "\n"
                "Foods: Apéritif, fish, and creamy dishes..\n";
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    default:
        break;
}
```

Comment: What is the reason to write two identical nested `switch` blocks (in viewDidLoad)? Half of this code never be called.

Comment: Why what happens?  Looks like you've got a memory leak (you allocate a `DetailViewController` but never `release` it).

Answer (score 0):

At least your code in `DetailView` has two nested switch statements that switch on the same variable `Wine`. This for example leads to the "Two Hands Canny Butcher Barossa Valley" to be unreachable as `Wine` cannot be zero and one at the same time. Perhaps you meant to use two variables and store both section and row for use in `DetailView`.

In any case I would recommend to remove data duplication and store everything in one place. If you, for example, stored all your wine information in an `NSArray` you could use this array to retrieve the data without using a large case statement. This also would allow to exchange the fixed list for something retrieved from a local database or even the web later.

If you, for example, created your own class `WineInformation` which contains properties for every aspect of the wine (name, alcohol content, recommended foods) you could simply pass the `WineInformation` object for the selected row to your `DetailView` which would then display the detailed information. This way you don't have to handle index paths or any of that stuff in `DetailView` and just concentrate of displaying the handed wine.